dual concept for height of an ideal
If $p$ is a prime ideal, then the supremum of lengths of chains of
primes descending from $p$ is called height of $p$ ( denoted $ht\ p$)
Is there a name for dual case:
the supremum of lengths of chains of primes ascending from $p$?

It is $\dim R/p$.
page 225 of the book Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry
by David Eisenbud
calls it $\dim p$.

But I didnt see somehow independent terminology ( not using $\dim$).
